# Is this inversion kosher? What is this kind of inversion called?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, inversion

> I didn't want confirmed what I suspected might be true

The adjective and noun seem inverted in this sentence. Is it grammatical? What is this kind of inversion called?

Comment: Yes, it's *kosher*.   Even elegant, in its own way.  I have no idea if there is a special name for it, though.

Comment: If you had put "confirmed" at the end, the sentence would have become unintelligible. Syntax often rules over _simple_ grammar.